# sql: case insensitive 'not in'?

Tags: sql

Need to parse some salesforce soql into standard sql, the issue is soql is case insensitive.

Been using lower() for the most part works, but the problem is with 'not in'.

```
lower(Tier__c) NOT IN lower(('E1','E2','E3', 'E4','Wholesale'))
```

does not work. What formatting would I need to get a case insensitive 'not in' to work?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to apply `lower()` to each element.  Or, find a case-insensitive collation for the comparison.

Comment: Case insensitive comparison is pretty much the default anyway. What kind of "standard sql" are you trying to convert to?

Comment: jdbctemplate uses case sensitive stuff.